# Как убрать текст внутри тега <ol> через javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Как убрать из `<ol>` текст не обернутый в тег `<li>`?

```html
<ol>
   текст
   <li>Текст</li>
   текст
</ol>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const ol = document.querySelector('ol');
// Получаем родительский элемент "ol"
const li = document.querySelectorAll('li');
// Получаем коллекцию дочерних элементов "li"
ol.textContent = '';
// Очищаем родительский элемент (пустая строка)
  for (item of li) {
ol.append(item);
}
// Проходимся циклом по коллекции дочерних  элементов и вставляем обратно
```

Comment: Все супер друг. Но решение выше проще, но твое решение тоже работает